# Scheduled local notifications at specific time in Android 13

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-13

> Hi guys, i am trying to scheduled local notifications at specific time in Android 13 but it is not working. I don't know how to fix the isse. Can any one help me on this.
> My code is here

```
public static void scheduleExactAlarm(Context context) {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            if (alarmManager == null) {
                // Handle the case where AlarmManager is not available
                return;
            }

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MYAlarmReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent.setAction("com.test.ACTION_MY_ALARM"); // Replace with your action

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context,
                    0,
                    alarmIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            );

            long triggerMillis = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes from now

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        triggerMillis,
                        pendingIntent
                );
            } else {
                alarmManager.setExact(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        triggerMillis,
                        pendingIntent
                );
            }
        }


`public class MYAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case "ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED":
                    Toast.makeText(context, "RECEIVED ALARM PERMISSION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case "from alarm":
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ALARM FIRED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
      }`

   <receiver
            android:name=".MYAlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.text.ACTION_MY_ALARM" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="from alarm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" /> <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

When i am trying with this code it is not workking on Android 12 and Android 13. I don't know how to fix this.
Is there something that i missed?

Comment: Have you requested permission for android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM from the user?

Comment: Did you ask the user to grant [POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission)? Without it, you can't send any non-exempt notifications yet on Android 13

Comment: yes granted the  POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission and also implemented the android. permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM. but the result remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

consider using new permission `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` (introduced in 12) and read dedicated [DOC](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/schedule-exact-alarms)